# Java Networking - Client and server

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm quite new to Java and have just started Networking so I apologize in advance for any stupid questions. I have a basic game in which a player (or bot) can move around a map until it finds items and exits, but using networking I'd like to be able for the player and the bot to play on the same map simultaneously over a server.

I have 5 classes:

- GameRules - Controls the game logic/rules
- Map - Contains the map.
- Player - Represents a player.
- Bot - Plays the game as a bot.
- PlayGame - Controls the interaction with the game through CLI.

I'm pretty sure GameRules and Map would be on the server side, and PlayGame would be on the client side, however I'm not sure where Bot and Player class stand? And also, do I merge GameRule and Map into one class, or put a socket in each class?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: One way or another, you will eventually have to share code between the two projects. That is the destiny of server-client architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Most models in a client-server game should reside both on client and server.

- The client needs the models to visualize the data they are holding;
- The server needs them to modify them according to business logic - the intermediate results are then sent to the clients to have their models updated. The server must do this because that is the reason for its existence: keeping the game's state consistent by being the only node that can alter the game state.

You can always try to keep all models at the clients but imagine what coding horror you'll get yourself into when you want to make a game with N clients. They all have to have a consistent state. It is far more safe to have one node (server) make decisions and then the other nodes must follow instructions.

Please note that in more advanced implementations, like realtime games, the client also implements some prediction behavior to hide the client-server delay, and thus temporarily alters the game state, but the server commands always overrule the client's decisions. You also can code the client in such a way that he is always able to keep playing even when he didn't receive a confirmation yet for the previous "moves" from the server - you have to implement rollback/correction functionality when some moves are denied by the server.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the business logic and synchronization timing needed, it's entirely possible to keep most everything at the client level, and just use the server as a broker for updates.  Imagine a 2-player online chess game.  The rules are so standard and the timing is simply back-and-forth, so a "server" of this game need only pass each move back and forth from one player to the other.  Would be like replacing the mail in your grandfather's chess match with a socket.  Each (client) side knows exactly how to process the move and what new moves are valid.